# What is the difference between tags [история-языка] and [history]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging, tag-synonyms

What is the difference between tags [история-языка](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0) and [history](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history)?

Should the latter be made a synonym for the former?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've merged them, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Aren't they separate? I think `language-history`/`история языка` is for a history of language, and `history`/`история` is a subject area (similar to mathematics or physics?).